# How can I use grep to display lines that start AND end with the same word

Tags: unix, grep

I am trying to figure out how to display lines that begin with 'world' AND end with 'world'.

I know grep '^world' displays any line starting with world and grep 'world$' displays lines which end with world.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to match the same word, you could use (if supported) `\w+` to match 1+ word characters and a back reference to the captured word.

```
^(\w+)\b.*\1$
```

- `^` Start of string

  - `(\w+)` Capture 1+ word chars in group 1
- `\b.*` Word boundary, match any char 0+ times
- `\1` Backreference to group 1
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/XZFC4X/1) | [Try it online (using GNU grep)](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/PzU5I19BqTy/KCdFoSS1uEQBzFRSqFFIL0otUNB1VVCP04gp19aMSdLTijFUUf//HwA)

For example

```
grep -E '^(\w+)\b.*\1$' file
```

To also match only `word`, you could make the rest of the pattern optional

```
grep -E '^(\w+)(\b.*\1)?$' file
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/qjMooz/1) | [Try it online (using GNU grep)](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/PzU5I19BqTy/KCdFSaFGIb0otUBB11VBPU4jplxbUyMmSU8rxlDTXkX9/38A)

Comment: @oguzismail I have added an addition that this example uses GNU grep.

Comment: Do you want to match `world test notworld` ?

Comment: Or `"a glass of tequila"`. Maybe add option `i` for `"World test world"`

Comment: @Walter yes I do as do I want to match 'world' as well.

Comment: @Thefourthbird that seems to work but not for 'world'. if the line is just world does it not start AND end with world

Comment: @elare That is correct as your question states `I am trying to figure out how to display lines that begin with 'world' AND end with 'world` :) But you could make what comes after the first word optional  `^(\w+)(\b.*\1)?$`  See https://regex101.com/r/qjMooz/1 and [try it online](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/PzU5I19BqTy/KCdFSaFGIb0otUBB11VBPU4jplxbUyMmSU8rxlDTXkX9/38A)